# How do I register user without being authenticated

Tags: forms, user-registration, notifications

I get form data through ajax and  I want to use it and add a new user with a subscriber role. to the original Wordpress users and also send them a notification about their account. 
Here is the bit of code that I have so far.

```
function set_form()
{
    $fisrt_name = $_POST['fisrt_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $admin =get_option('admin_email');
    //Code to register user

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_set_form', 'set_form');    //execute when wp logged in
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_set_form', 'set_form'); //execute when logged out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [wp_insert_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) function to create the new user. And then with the [wp_new_user_notification](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_new_user_notification/) function you could send the notification.